# Google Cloud SDK 0.9.39 still fails to do setup-managed-vms

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just updated my gcloud components on my OS X Mavericks laptop, so now I have:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.39

$ boot2docker version
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.3.2
Git commit: e41a9ae
```

I was hoping managed vms setup would work, but alas:

```
$ gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms
Select the runtime to download the base image for:
 [1] Go
 [2] Java
 [3] Python27
 [4] All
Please enter your numeric choice (4):  2

Pulling base images for runtimes [java] from Google Cloud Storage
Pulling image: google/appengine-java
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 171, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 385, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 928, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/setup_managed_vms.py", line 39, in Run
    args.image_version)
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/pull.py", line 54, in PullBaseDockerImages
    util.PullSpecifiedImages(docker_client, image_names, version, bucket)
  File "/Users/hussein/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/util.py", line 232, in PullSpecifiedImages
    'Error pulling {image}: {e}'.format(image=image_name, e=e))
googlecloudsdk.appengine.lib.images.util.DockerPullError: Error pulling google/appengine-java: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid registry endpoint "http://localhost:49153/v1/". HTTPS attempt: Get https://localhost:49153/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49153: connection reset by peer. HTTP attempt: Get http://localhost:49153/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49153: connection reset by peer")
```

I'm very new to Docker and managed vas, and I'm wondering if the issue is due to my boot2docker port forwarding setup. My env is setup correctly I think;

```
$ env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/h/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
```

With the docker host IP being:

```
$ boot2docker ip
docker@localhost's password: 

The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103
```

Finally, the containers on my system so far are:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED               STATUS                           PORTS                    NAMES
73c6d317a631        google/docker-registry:latest     "./run.sh"          2 minutes ago           Exited (-1) About a minute ago                            goofy_archimedes                   
40b709d6fa00        gcloud-credentials-image:latest   "/true"             2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                                  gcloud-credentials-1417828737.2    
a3073bc56ff2        google/docker-registry:latest     "./run.sh"          47 hours ago        Exited (-1) 47 hours ago                                  distracted_bell                    
1b6fe130af45        11cd171d89b3                      "/true"             47 hours ago        Exited (0) 47 hours ago                                   gcloud-credentials-1417707423.48   
28c181e66b11        google/docker-registry:latest     "./run.sh"          2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 minutes ago         0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   elegant_darwin
```

Then why is gcloud python script trying to access the registry on localhost? Someone, please show me the light!

Comment: So, after some digging, it turns out one has to manually setup port forwarding between Virtual Box and the host (os x) in order for the google scripts to work, like shown in:http://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide

Comment: I tried the link your provided to forward ports, but I still get the same error as you. Did you end up solving it? It's driving me insane!